# Identity Map with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a native way with Mongoose 4.x to maintain a identity map and avoid returning different object instances for the same entity in the DB?

```
Users.findOne({_id: ObjectId("XXX")}, function(err, user1) {
  if (err) throw err;
  Users.findOne({_id: ObjectId("XXX")}, function(err, user2) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log(user1 === user2); // Return FALSE
  });
});
```

Comment: Mongoose by default returns a Document and not a JS object with the query `findOne()`. If you want a plain JavaScript object, which you can natively change its properties, you need to specify the [**`lean()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) option: `Users.findOne({_id: ObjectId("XXX")}).lean().exec(callback);` This way tells Mongoose to skip the step of creating the full model instance and you can then directlt get objects which you can compare.

Comment: @chridam, I mean if there is a native mongoose-way to track Documents identities, and don't fetch an already fetched document from the DB. (like in Doctrine that implements [Identity Mapper + Unit of work](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map) for tracking changes)

Comment: Pretty sure that Mongoose doesn't have that.